# Serving Flask app with waitress on windows using SSL public/private key

Tags: python, flask, waitress, sll

How do I run my Flask app which uses SSL keys using waitress.  The SSL context is specified in my Flask's run() as in

```
                       app.run(ssl_context=('cert.pem', 'key.pem'))
```

But app.run() is not used when using waitress as in the code below.  So, where do I specify the keys?  Thanks for the help.

```
   from flask import Flask, request
   app = Flask(__name__)

   @app.route("/")
   def hello():
       return "Hello World!"

  if __name__ == '__main__':
  #   app.run(ssl_context=('../cert.pem', '../key.pem'))
      from waitress import serve
      serve(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=5000)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At the current version (1.4.3), Waitress does not natively support TLS.

See TLS support in https://github.com/Pylons/waitress/blob/36240c88b1c292d293de25fecaae1f1d0ad9cc22/docs/reverse-proxy.rst

You either need a reverse proxy in front to handle the tls/ssl part, or use another WSGI server (CherryPy, Tornado...).

Comment: Any idea if this has changed or do we still need to use a reverse proxy?

Comment: I believe it is the same (no change in documentation : https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/waitress/en/latest/reverse-proxy.html#using-behind-a-reverse-proxy)